# Using a slider control to dyanimcally load pages?

Tags: ajax, slider

I was wondering if it is possible to use a slider to dynamically load pages with ajax. Basically I wanted the users to be able to slide the bar over to specific months, and these months would be individual pages that would dynamically load content.

[Here's a design example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8u34.jpg)

If anyone knows any resources for starters, I would greatly appreciate it!